# SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens - help needed

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, pdo

I've tried making a website which has a database connected to it and I'm getting the error message below

```
INSERT INTO Diák (oktatási_id,  vezeték_név,  kereszt_név,  évfolyam,  születési_dátum,  város,  utca,  házszám,  irányítószám,  szak,  kar) 
         values (:oktatási_id, :vezeték_név, :kereszt_név, :évfolyam, :születési_dátum, :város, :utca, :házszám, :irányítószám, :szak, :kar)
```

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables
>   does not match number of tokens

This is my PHP code that I have written below

```
<?php

require "../config.php";
require "../common.php";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  if (!hash_equals($_SESSION['csrf'], $_POST['csrf'])) die();

  try  {
    $connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);

    $new_user = array(
      "oktatási_id" => $_POST['oktatási_id'],
      "vezeték_név"  => $_POST['vezeték_név'],
      "kereszt_név"     => $_POST['kereszt_név'],
      "évfolyam"       => $_POST['évfolyam'],
      "születési_dátum" => $_POST['születési_dátum'],
      "város"  => $_POST['város'],
      "utca"  => $_POST['utca'],
      "házszám" => $_POST['házszám'],
      "irányítószám" => $_POST['irányítószám'],
      "szak" => $_POST['szak'],
      "kar" => $_POST['kar'],

    );

    $sql = sprintf(
      "INSERT INTO %s (%s) values (%s)",
      "Diák",
      implode(", ", array_keys($new_user)),
      ":" . implode(", :", array_keys($new_user))
    );

    $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $statement->execute($new_user);
  } catch(PDOException $error) {
      echo $sql . "<br>" . $error->getMessage();
  }
}
?>
<?php require "templates/header.php"; ?>

  <?php if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $statement) : ?>
    <blockquote><?php echo escape($_POST['kereszt_név']); ?> adatát sikeresen hozzá adtuk az adatbázishoz.</blockquote>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <h2>Felhasználó hozzáadása az adatbázishoz</h2>

  <form method="post">
    <input name="csrf" type="hidden" value="<?php echo escape($_SESSION['csrf']); ?>">
    <label for="oktatási_id">oktatási_id</label>
    <input type="text" name="oktatási_id" id="oktatási_id">
    <label for="vezeték_név">Vezeték Név</label>
    <input type="text" name="vezeték_név" id="vezeték_név">
    <label for="kereszt_név">Kereszt Név</label>
    <input type="text" name="kereszt_név" id="kereszt_név">
    <label for="évfolyam">évfolyam</label>
    <input type="text" name="évfolyam" id="évfolyam">
    <label for="születési_dátum">Születési dátum</label>
    <input type="date" name="születési_dátum" id="születési_dátum">
    <label for="város">város</label>
    <input type="text" name="város" id="város">
    <label for="utca">utca</label>
    <input type="text" name="utca" id="utca">
    <label for="házszám">házszám</label>
    <input type="text" name="házszám" id="házszám">
    <label for="irányítószám">irányítószám</label>
    <input type="text" name="irányítószám" id="irányítószám">
    <label for="kar">kar</label>
    <input type="text" name="kar" id="kar">
    <label for="szak">szak</label>
    <input type="text" name="szak" id="szak">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>

  <a href="index.php">Vissza a kezdő oldalra</a>

<?php require "templates/footer.php"; ?>
```

Comment: It looks like you are building SQL statements partially with string manipulating, and then massaging this String. You should dump these Strings to the console as you massage them and inspect them to see if you are even making legal statements. Because that message is usually about malformed statements. In short: you need to do some debugging.

Comment: Please show us the result of `var_dump($sql)` and also `var_dump($new_user);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a while to find, but I believe that PDO::prepare passes the named parameters through a regular expression `[:][a-zA-Z0-9_]+`. https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/pdo/pdo_sql_parser.re#L48. Your diacritic characters are being clobbered.

The only alternative that I know about it to use unnamed placeholders instead - `?`. Something like:

```
$sql = sprintf(
    "INSERT INTO %s (%s) values (%s)",
    "Diak",
    implode(", ", array_keys($new_user)),
    implode(', ', array_fill(0, sizeof($new_user), '?'))
);
```

Which will produce:

`INSERT INTO Diák (oktatási_id, vezeték_név, kereszt_név, évfolyam, születési_dátum, város, utca, házszám, irányítószám, szak, kar) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`

You'll then have to change your execute method as follows:

`$statement->execute(array_values($new_user));`